# How to change an individual element based on a class jquery callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, this

I want to be able to create a "click" response for a class and then change the CSS of the particular element that was clicked.

This does not seem to be working. I thought using `$(this)` would indicate the particular element but it doesn't seem to. One complicating issue is I am overriding an external stylesheet.

My jquery code:

```
$('.myClass').click( function() {
    $('this').css("width: 30% !important");
    alert("THIS ALERT WORKS");
})
```

The alert does work. I have static CSS that is able to change `.myClass`.

My HTML:

```
<button class="classA classB myClass" type="submit">Button</button>
```

I also tried `$('this').val("")` and that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.myClass').click( function(){
    $(this).css('width', '30%');
    // or $(this).css('width', '30% !important');  
})
```

In your code there are two mistakes

**1.**

```
$('this') should be $(this)
```

**2.**

`$('this').css("width: 30% !important");` should be `$('this').css("width", "30% !important");`

if you want change more than one option you can do it like this

```
$(this).css({backgroundColor: "green", borderColor: "black", borderWidth: "30px"});
```

//  or

```
$(this).css({'background-color': "green", 'border-color': "black", 'border-width': "30px"});
```

[$.css - on this page](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2) you can find good explanation about `$.css` syntax

Answer (score 2):

your syntax is wrong, it should be

```
  $(this).css("width", "30% !important");
```

or

```
  $(this).css({"width": "30% !important"});
```

not

```
  $(this).css("width: 30% !important");
```

You need to separate the attribute from its value.

**UPDATE**

If you want to edit multiple attributes I wouldn't use `.css()` at all. I would use `addClass` and tack on a CSS class instead. That way it's less overhead for JS. ex:

**JS**

```
$(this).addClass("adjust")
```

**CSS**

```
.adjust{
   background-color: green; 
   border-color: black;
   border-width: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Would you do this for multiple changes?
$(this).css("background-color", "green", "border-color", "black", "border-width", "30px");

Comment: @Bren you can use object for this case, like this http://jsbin.com/cohupe/1/edit?js

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.myClass').click( function(){
  $(this).css('width', '30%');
  alert("THIS ALERT WORKS");
});
```

[Live demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/raWOvm)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('.myClass').click( function(){
            $('this').css("width", "30% !important");
            alert("THIS ALERT WORKS");
    })
```